# Committing for documentation with 2 accounts

Tags: support, documentation, duplicate-accounts

Having 2 accounts (one at work and one at home), I need to be careful with voting twice, flagging twice etc. I know I must not do anything I were not able to do with one account.

Is it correct to assume that I may not commit for documentation twice? So the "workaround" would be to wait for enough users to commit and then participate.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Just curious: Why the 2 accounts?

Comment: @Cerbrus: my employer wanted me to use one at work and one in my free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already assumed it and @[Stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/247702/stijn) also says in the comments:

> Of course you shouldn't do that.